# next/previous track buttons action

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, qtkit

I have an NSTableView (URLs of songs) and QTMovieView elements. I need to create an action that will execute when previous/next buttons on QTMovieView will be pressed. what I need to do?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do custom things, don't use the QTMovieView's control bar. You'll have to make your own controls with their own actions. Those actions will do what you need them to do as well as tell the movie view to play/pause, seek, etc.

You can turn the control bar off on a QTMovieView. Since you appear not to be using the video portion of the movie view, however, you could get rid of it entirely, using your own controls.